# Monotouch: how to verify UITextFields

Tags: uitextfield, xamarin.ios

I have several UITextFields that I want to do a numeric check on when the user taps the Next key on the keyboard.  I know I can do it when the k/b becomes first responder... I want to check the field before the user goes on to the next field.

How do I do this?

Comment: I Don't really understand .. You wan't to check the value in the current TextField, before the user goes to the next TextField?

Comment: yes, that's right!  Since I have about 6 UITextFields, I thought it might be nice to tell the user that they entered non-numeric data in a numeric-only UITextField

Comment: Go to interface builder, select the textfield, go to "events" and drag "editing changed" to files owner. Select the IBAction method you wan't to use. That should be it :)

Comment: Easier: make sure that the keypad for the UITextField is set to numeric only ;-)

Answer (score 0):

void HandleTxtHIhandleEditingDidEnd (object sender, EventArgs e)  {
    if(!decimal.TryParse(txtHI.Text, out x))  {